# How to control over data precision when saving dataframe to dbf in R

Tags: r, precision, dbf

I have a file in a dbf format, which I want to read into R and do a small manipulation.

```
library(foreign)
library(dplyr)
library(spsurvey)

### set working directory
coverage <- foreign::read.dbf("coverage.dbf")

coverage_adj <- mutate(coverage, VAR1 = replace(VAR1, VAR2 == "X" & VAR1 == "Y", "Z" ))

write.dbf(coverage_adj, "coverage_adj.dbf")
```

Everything works as I expect despite the fact, that numeric columns from coverage table loose their precision after saving.

For example column VAR3 is originally a numeric with 2 decimal points. This is how it shows in R:

```
> head(coverage$VAR3)
[1]  163.78   34.61 1063.97  212.78    6.93   91.46
```

Adjusted table in R also looks okey so numeric with 2 decimal points:

```
> head(coverage_adj$VAR3)
[1]  163.78   34.61 1063.97  212.78    6.93   91.46
```

However after write.dbf(), if I open the saved file in Excel of FoxPro I can see:

163.780000000000000
34.609999999999900
1063.970000000000000
212.780000000000000

Is there a way to preserve the datatypes and their precision while saving a dbf from R?

Comment: This is covered in the first chapter of the R inferno. One idea is to simply round your results after manipulating them with `round(..., digits=2)`

Comment: @mts Would that mean that before saving a dbf I have to round every numeric value to a type specified in the dbf?

Comment: that depends how critical precision is for your uses afterwards. in your case the difference manifests at the 10th digit. while if won't hurt, you should know if it is worth your troubles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want more insight on why this is happening, check the first circle of the [R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf) (a quick and easy read). Basically R is storing your floating points with a numerical error, but when showing you `head(coverage_adj$VAR3)` it is hiding that.

In your case the easiest thing to do is use `round(..., digits=2)` on your data before saving again, e.g:

```
write.dbf(round(coverage_adj, digits=2), "coverage_adj.dbf")
```

That should be all you need.